# App Store Binary rejected for white screen displayed unable to review

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, app-store, ios-simulator

I was uploaded the build to App Store first time on three month ago. It got published successfully.(Ionic App for iOS)

Now I made small changes in the app and try to update the app without affect the existing functionality. But App Store review team has rejected my build for the following reason:

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone and
>   iPad running iOS 12.1 on Wi-Fi.
>
> Specifically, upon review we have found the White screen is displayed
>   on device and unable to review.
>
> The steps to reproduce are:
>
> 1.) downloaded app
>   2.) launched app
>   3.) white screen displayed and unable to review

However, we checked the app thoroughly and there is no such white blank screen appeared.What would be the reason for rejection and how to solve this issue?

Comment: are you tried in 3g or 2g or slow network ,check once and add the activity indicator before data load

Comment: does apple sent you that white blank screen? If not then you can contact them and ask for that screen.

Comment: we testing the app over wi-fi @Anbu.karthik let me try in slow network.

Comment: @Kuldeep yeah we got blank screenshot from review team

Comment: white screen its your current VC background color

Comment: @Muthuraja have you updated your splash screen in this release or name changed for splash image

Comment: @iOS_Developer no changes in splashscreen, this release shipped only with issue fixes and UI alignments

Comment: @Muthuraja and there is actually white screen appearing? Share video link please. or some code. for clarity.

Comment: I would suggest you install a TestFlight build on as device that has never had your app installed (an iPad if you have one, since that is often what they review with) and see what happens

Comment: @Paulw11 Found the issue. Tested through TestFlight and issue was in binary build (which was submitted for review) Thank you and everyone!

Comment: @Muthuraja I am facing this same white screen error which i could not reproduce in development. How did resolved this issue? What was the root cause? Can u pls help